# Parameter is not passing from extjs grid to servlet page

Tags: java, servlets, extjs4

In my application I am passing parameters from grid to servlet page. But in servlet it is coming as `null`. Any idea what is wrong in my code..
Note: From this servlet page I am taking data for another grid.

Function to pass parameter:

```
   function callAjaxToCheckSession(selected)
   {   alert(selected);
        Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: 'YieldCurveServlet',


   method:'POST',
   headers: {'application/json'},
   params: {
       YCSET_ID: selected

     },
   success: function(response, opts) {
      var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
      console.dir(obj);
   },
   failure: function(response, opts) {
      console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
   }
});
   }
```

In this I am getting value in an alert. and same value in http header (request payload YCSET:value). But in servlet it is coming as null.
Here is my servlet :

```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String val = request.getParameter("YCSET_ID");
    System.out.println(val);
```

Here is header Part:

```
   Request Method:POST
   Status Code:200 OK
    **Request Headers**
    Accept:*/*
   Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
    Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
     Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:21
    Content-type: text/html
    Cookie:JSESSIONID=5621DF422D5E54A4EFFD29E5868A40FE
    X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

   **Request Payload**
    YCSET_ID=SPREAD_CURVE

    **Response Headers**
 Content-Length:56
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 24 Dec 2013 12:48:13 GMT
    Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Any suggestion to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the value send as parameter in the request with the getParameter function, so uncomment the line :

```
String val = request.getParameter("YCSET_ID")
```

Comment: actually initially I was using request.getParameter.But it wasn't working. so I tried with request.getAttribute().Still same problem.only null is coming to servlet.

Comment: Can you use a tool as fiddler or with the chrome developer tools to see the complete request and check if the parameter is send.

Comment: yeah I checked in chrome and above I have posted the header part of http request.I removed the local host name because I don't have enough reputation to post the links.There you can see in Request payload it is passing the parameter.

Comment: That's a strange behaviour, You can iterate over the request parameters names to check if it parameter is in the server you could use the function request.getParameterNames()

Comment: I solved this issue by changing the method from POST to GET. it is working fine. thank u anyway.

Comment: Hey I have one more question.After retrieving correct response how to display that in second grid. I mean how to reconfigure that grid?

Answer (score 0):

`request.getParameter("parameter_name");` works for query string parameters and form data. To get JSON data serverside from a `request` try this:

```
BufferedReader buff = request.getReader();
String json = buff.readLine();
if (!json.startsWith("[")) {
    json = "[" + json + "]";
}
```

The `if` part works when you have a single value on your array and it looks more like an object. That way you can treat it as an array always.

Comment: I got the solution . I only changed the method from POST to GET.